# Python3 NameError: name 'method' is not defined for defined @staticmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, recursion, nameerror

I am trying to write a simple recursive function in python3. As I am learning OO  Java, I also want to write Python code involving objects. Here's my code below. I prompt the user to enter a number and the screen should display every integer smaller until 5.

```
class Recursion:
    @staticmethod
    def recursive(x):
        if (x>5):
            print (x)
            recursive(x - 1)

def main(self):
    x = int(input('Enter a number for recursive addition: '))
    recursive(x)
```

However, when I run it on a terminal, it says: "NameError: name 'recursive' is not defined". Here's what the error looks like:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Recursion import *
>>> a = Recursion()
>>> a.main()
Enter a number for recursive addition: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ZycinG/Desktop/Python Practice/Recursion.py", line 9, in main
    recursive(x)
NameError: name 'recursive' is not defined
```

What causes the problem here? I know how to just write the recursive function, give it an argument, and let it run on the terminal. But I want to practice OOP.

Comment: well you don't really have to write it in a class, but the second should work, could you please provide the code that you use to actually call `main` in the first place?

Comment: Ignore my comment about not writing it in the class, missed the last statement, but it might make sense to make it a `staticmethod` if it doesn't actually use data from an object.

Comment: with the second code block you provided and the statement `Recursion().main()` below the class definition and entering `10` when prompted the program works as expected. Well, disregarding that "recursive addition" actually counts down to 6.

Comment: Whezn you post a question about errors, please remember to show the steps that lead to error, not just your code + "I used it". It is quite possible that your error lies in the execution and not in the preparation

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thank you for your reply. Here's my new code with staticmethod and it still says name not defined?                                 `class Recursion:
 @staticmethod
 def recursive(x):
  if (x>5):
   print (x)
   recursive(x - 1)
 def main(self):
  x = int(input('Enter a number for recursive addition: '))
  recursive(x)`

Comment: please edit your question instead of pasting code in comments (very hard to use) and include the **main body of code** that executes the main method.  as @Mixone stated the error is likely caused by something you did not include.

Comment: I'm sorry guys if my comment is kind of messy. I'm new to stackoverflow. :(

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Okay, I have edited my post.

Comment: oh dear, now I regret my suggestion to use staticmethod... I'm sorry let me try to make it up...

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Don't worry about the staticmethod at all man, I can change it back easily, I really appreciate your effort ;)

Comment: @Mixone Thank you for your advice, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

consider you have the function defined in the global scope:

```
def recursive(x):
    if (x>5):
        print (x)
        recursive(x - 1)
```

you would simply call this with `recusive(10)` from elsewhere in the program and similarly from within the function, if you make it a `staticmethod` within a class:

```
class Recursion:
    @staticmethod
    def recursive(x):
        if (x>5):
            print (x)
            recursive(x - 1) #this isn't how you call it any more
```

now it is stored in the global scope as `Recursion.recursive` so that is also how you would have to refer to it within the function:

```
class Recursion:
    @staticmethod
    def recursive(x):
        if (x>5):
            print (x)
            Recursion.recursive(x - 1)
```

However if you want a method to have access to the class scope directly (locally to the function) you can label it a `classmethod`:

```
class Recursion:
    @classmethod
    def recursive(cls,x): #the first argument is the class
        if (x>5):
            print (x)
            cls.recursive(x - 1)
```

this has several benefits, first that it can be called as `Recursion.recursive(10)` or `x = Recursion() ; x.recursive()` but also that it will use a subclass if appropriate instead of always using `Recursion`:

```
class Recursion:
    def __init__(self,x=None):
        raise NotImplementedError("not intended to initialize the super class")
    @classmethod
    def recursive(x):
        if (x>5):
            print (x)
            cls.recursive(x - 1)
        else:
            return cls(x)

class R_sub(Recursion):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self._val = x
#now using R_sub.recursive(10) will work fine
```

although even if you do not use `staticmethod` or `classmethod` you still need to refer to the method, as a method: (in java you can use the methods just by name but python basically forces you to use methods as `self.METHOD` similarly to java's `this.METHOD`)

```
class Recursion:
    def recursive(self,x):
        if (x>5):
            print (x)
            self.recursive(x - 1)
```

Hope this clears things up about how methods work in python!

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your answer and it makes how method works in python a lot more clear to me! As Java was my first language, the transition is a bit confusing sometimes. Haha.

Comment: no problem, have fun coding and Welcome to StackOverflow!