# Guess number, no such attribute, python 3

Tags: oop, python-3.x

I'm learning OOP in python and was trying to run this small game in OOP style, but for some reason system doesn't find object's attributes.

Here's the problem:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "HelloUsername.py", line 47, in <module>
>     newGameGTN = GuessTheNumber()
> File "HelloUsername.py", line 6, in __init__
>     self.start_game()
> File "HelloUsername.py", line 32, in start_game
>     player = player_choice()
> NameError: name 'player_choice' is not defined
> ```

On this code in python 3:

```
from random import randint
class GuessTheNumber(object):
    """docstring for GuessTheNumber"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_game()
        self.player_choice()
        self.compare_numbers()

    def player_choice(self):
        choice = int(input("Choose your number: "))
        if choice in range(101):
                return(choice)
            else:
                print("Please enter a number 0-100")
                player_choice()

    def compare_numbers(self, computer, player):
        if player == computer:
            return(0)
        elif player > computer:
            return(1)
        elif player < computer:
            return(-1)

    def start_game(self):
        computer = randint(0, 100)
        turn = 0
        for turn in range(3):
            player = player_choice()
            x = compare_numbers(computer, player)
            print(computer)
            if x == -1:
                print("too small")
            elif x == 1:
                print("too big")    
            elif x == 0:
                print("you win")
                break   
                turn += 1
            print("game over")

newGameGTN = GuessTheNumber()
newGameGTN.start_game()
```

Comment: Since the functions `player_choice` and `compare_numbers` are *within* the class, they are passed around internally via the `self` object. Hence, calling `self.player_choice()` should work

Comment: You may be interested in using `classmethod` or `staticmethod` since the object is not really required for the methods, you can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076506/python3-nameerror-name-method-is-not-defined/36088022#36088022) for a description on how they work but jDo got it exactly: you need to call `self.player_choice()` instead of just `player_choice()`

Comment: What does this have to do with Sublime Text? Please don't tag your text editor unless the problem is with the editor itself.

Answer (score 0):

`NameError` is not the same as `AttributeError` (which you mention in the question's summary).  A `NameError` exception means that the name referenced in your code does not exist.  A name can be a local variable, or a variable in an enclosing scope.

All methods in a class need to be called on an instance of that class.  (staticmethods and classmethods not withstanding)  Instead of `name = player_choice()` you need to write `name = self.player_choice()`.  Likewise for all other occurrences where you call a method defined in the class.