# NameError: name 'distancepoint' is not defined

Tags: python, class, point

```py
import math
class point:
    def __init__(self,p1,p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
    def distancepoint(self):
        x1,y1 = self.p1
        x2,y2 = self.p2
        distance = math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
        return distance
p1 = point(2,4)
p2 = point(1,6)

distance = distancepoint(p1,p2)
print (f'Distance between 2 points: {distance}')
```

I am a Python beginner. I dont know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 NameError: name 'method' is not defined for defined @staticmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076506/python3-nameerror-name-method-is-not-defined-for-defined-staticmethod) (Other than this obvious point of `distancepoint` being a method, `p1` and `p2` in your code a objects of `point` and `self.p1` and `self.p2` are integers. `x1,y1 = self.p1` will give you an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

- The way your code is written, `distancepoint` should be a regular function (outside of a class), that takes two point objects as an input and returns a distance:

```py
import math


class Point: # python devs usually use CamelCase for class names
    def __init__(self, x, y): # x and y, because we have two coordinates, not two points
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y


def distancepoint(p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1.x, p1.y
    x2, y2 = p2.x, p2.y

    distance = math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)
    return distance



p1 = Point(2, 4)
p2 = Point(1, 6)

distance = distancepoint(p1, p2)
print(f"Distance between 2 points: {distance}")
```

- Another way to go about it, which you seemed to be aiming at, is to define `distancepoint` as a method of the `Point` class. That means you can measure the distance
  from a given `Point` object to another `Point`.

```py
class Point: # python devs usually use CamelCase for class names
    def __init__(self, x, y): # x and y, because we have two coordinates, not two points
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y


    def distance(self, other_p):
        x1, y1 = self.x, self.y
        x2, y2 = other_p.x, other_p.y

        distance = math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)
        return distance

p1 = Point(2, 4)
p2 = Point(1, 6)

distance = p1.distance(p2)
print(f"Distance between 2 points: {distance}")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're confused about your variables: in the point class definition, p1 and p2 are point coordinates, and distancepoint is a class method, while later p1 and p2 are points, and you try to use distancepoint as a function (outside a class); here's what you probably wanted to do:

```
import math
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def distancepoint(self, other):
        distance = math.sqrt((self.x - other.x)**2 + (self.y - other.y)**2)
        return distance
p1 = point(2,4)
p2 = point(1,6)

distance = p1.distancepoint(p2)
print (f'Distance between 2 points: {distance}')

# Distance between 2 points: 2.23606797749979
```

Answer (score 0):

by looking at the code seems like you are trying to write a program to get the distance between two points if I am correct try this code.

your code actually calls a method which is a class method and you are calling it without an object which is not callable.

```
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def distance_to(self, other_point):
        return math.sqrt((self.x - other_point.x)**2 + (self.y - other_point.y)**2)

p1 = Point(2, 4)
p2 = Point(1, 6)

distance = p1.distance_to(p2)
print(f'Distance between 2 points: {distance}')
```